# Convert a string parameter into float in Cloudant query

Tags: node.js, nosql, ibm-cloud, cloudant

I need to do a query in an Cloudant DataBase where you compare a number with decimals that is defined as a string with another number sent from the server. The problem is that a comparison of strings is made and I need it to be a numerical comparison. There is there any way to perform this search by converting the database parameter to float while doing the query? O there are another way to do this query?

This is the query in the server, value.precio is sent from the client as a string.

```
        value.precio = value.precio.split("-");
        var precio_init = value.precio[0];
        var precio_final = value.precio[1];  

        value.precio = {
          "$gte":precio_init,
          "$lte":precio_final
        };
```

And in my database this is the parameter I want to search is:

"precio": "13.39"

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a specific example and describe the relevant part of the documents you are trying to query?

Comment: I edited my question... I hope it's enough Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you will be able to do this with Cloudant Query, but you could try Cloudant Search. Create a new search index similar to the following:

Design Doc: myDesignDoc

Index Name: byPrecio

Index:

```
function (doc) {
  if (doc.precio) {
    index("precio", parseFloat(doc.precio));
  }
}
```

Then you can uses ranges to search. For example:

```
precio:[13 TO 14]
```

Full search on Cloudant would look like this:

https://xxx.cloudant.com/YOUR_DB/_design/myDesignDoc/_search/byPrecio?q=precio:[13%20TO%2014]&include_docs=true

Sample response:

```
{
  "total_rows":1,
  "bookmark":"g2wAAAAxxx",
  "rows":[
    {
      "id":"74fa6ff1b6dbca8c10d677832f6a3de2",
      "order":[
        1.0,
        0
      ],
      "fields":{

      },
      "doc":{
        "_id":"74fa6ff1b6dbca8c10d677832f6a3de2",
        "_rev":"2-17c984e51102b719fe9f80fc5d5bc78e",
        "precio":"13.39",
        "otherField":"otherValue"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

[More info on Cloudant Search here](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/Cloudant/api/search.html#search)

Comment: Hi there... I'm not trying to make the transformation in the cloudant query. I used the desing Doc you gave us but the cloudant query precio:[13 TO 14] is not working. Thanks for you response

Comment: This uses Cloudant Search not Cloudant Query. Are you using Cloudant Search? https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/Cloudant/api/search.html#search